# Message Broker (Kafka, RabbitMQ) VS Service Bus (nServiceBus)

Tags: .net, wcf, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I've read a lot about the three mentioned systems. But I am still not sure what to use. They all seem to accomplish what I need:

I want a client service/services to be updated when another service fires an event/command/message. I am currently running `WCF` Services and a client service can actively ask for updated data from other services. This should be changed with a message broker/service bus. 
I also don't care if the client goes offline and doesn't receive updates, since when going online it automatically gets the latest data via `WCF` anyway. 
That's why I am thinking `Kafka` is the wrong approach. On the other hand I deploy this software in a security related context at other companies. And since this is a legacy application (no docker or easy deployment), needing to install Erlang, open all ports for `RabbitMQ` is not an option. This leaves me with `NServiceBus`.

1. Do I miss out on anything crucial when running only `NServiceBus`, instead of the often seen `RabbitMQ+NServiceBus` variant?
2. It seems as long as I am using the `.net` stack exclusively, I am good with `NServiceBus`?
3. Since I already have `WCF` to poll for updated data, should you only send a command to initiate the `WCF` call. Or should you send the updated data itself via the messaging system directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: I'm a developer at Particular Software, makers of NServiceBus. I apologize if this sounds too much as a commercial.

> Since I already have WCF to poll for updated data

I'm not sure what you mean by that. It could be that you're already using messaging with WCF on top of MSMQ. That is possible and a viable solution. MSMQ is the queuing technology and WCF is an abstraction on top of MSMQ.

MSMQ, RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus, Amazon SQS are all queuing technologies, although MSMQ is a bit different since it's more a bus style and distributed across machines.

NServiceBus is an abstraction on top of these queuing technologies. NServiceBus lets you focus on developing features instead of writing plumbing code on top of a single queuing technology. On top of that, it adds tons of additional features. If you decide not to use NServiceBus, you have to build some of these features yourself. Which is perfectly fine, but requires time.

To answer specific questions

1. If using NServiceBus, you still need a queuing technology, which we call `transport`. Either MSMQ or RabbitMQ or whatever you want.
2. For sure, but it's still possible to integrate natively, like you would do when messaging between Java and .NET
3. That depends. Sending it via the message is usually more reliable and faster/easier, because you don't have to do the WCF call. Besides that, you can slowly remove WCF and need less developers with WCF knowledge.

If you have more questions, don't hesitate to contact us at https://particular.net/support/

Comment: Thank you. 
Is there a tutorial or project in which a webClient is updated via NServiceBus? I found the eShopOnContainers from Microsoft so far.

Comment: eShopOnContainers is quite difficult and we don't agree completely on the chosen architecture. Perhaps you're looking for this show case sample, where the front-end is asynchronously updated via messaging and SignalR.
https://docs.particular.net/samples/showcase/